# google sheets Forecast, Trend, Growth function #errors (formula parse errors)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, forecasting, trend

I'm trying to use google sheets Forecast, Trend, or Growth function and it keeps throwing me  #errors (formula parse errors) when I use anyone of them (and I tried various variations). I tried it on existing data, I tried to populate new data. It looks like the formula I'm using is ok and it must be something else I'm missing. Did someone have a similair experience?

[image]

[image]

Comment: A sample sheet would be great help. In any case, most likely the dates in column `A` or the numbers in `B` are not formatted correctly. Use column `C` as a temp helper column. Place in `C2` the formula `=TYPE(A1)` and drug down. Check your results. Repeat for column `B`. Read more about [`TYPE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267375?hl=en-GB)

Comment: @ marikamitsos thank you for your input, everything was formatted correctly but it your remark did make me thinking, I put the spreadsheet settings to U.S. and now it works, thanks :)